# Insert swal inside the function not working

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I tried the default code from sweetalert.com it is working means I have my import link. Im trying to put it inside the function for some reason. Here is my code:

**This swal code is not working**

```
<html>
<head>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
 </script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js">
 </script>
 </head>
<title></title>
<body>
<form onclick="myFunctions()">  
<button> Try </button>
<script>
function myFunctions(){
swal("Hello world!");
}
</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the script containing the swal function definition?

Comment: line 9. Simple swal

Answer (score 0):

You forgot import CDN in   like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="clickme" > Try </button>




<script>

$(document).ready(

function myFunctions(){

    $("#clickme").click(function(){
        swal("Hello world!");
    });


}
)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```